# 424 error VBA when i display JSON content on MsgBox

Tags: excel, vba

When trying to display my JSON content in a MsgBox to check it, I get the 424 error, as much as I search I can't identify the problem. Somebody could help me ?

My code is the following. I am a bit newbie in VBA

```
Sub LoopThroughRowsByList()
   Dim iListRow As ListRow
   Dim iCol As Range
   Dim cellValue As String
   Dim arr3
   Dim count As Integer
   Dim XMLHTTP
   Set XMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.serverXMLHTTP")
 
   Dim jsonItems As New Collection
   Dim jsonDictionary As New Dictionary
   Dim i As Long
    
    arr3 = Array("RequestType", "ItemCode", "Creator", "ResourceID", _
       "AccountCode", "Description", "OpportunityID", "TextFreeField1", _
       "TextFreeField8", "TextFreeField13", "TextFreeField14", _
       "DateFreeField2", "AmountFreeField4", "AmountFreeField5", _
        "NumberFreeField1")

    
    For Each iListRow In ActiveSheet.ListObjects("tabla").ListRows
        count = 0
        For Each iCol In iListRow.Range
            If iCol.Value <> "" Then
                cellValue = iCol.Value
                jsonDictionary(arr3(count)) = cellValue
            Else
                Exit For
            End If
            count = count + 1
         Next iCol
         jsonItems.Add jsonDictionary
         If IsEmpty(cellValue) Then
            Exit For
         End If

         Dim myurl As String
         myurl = "myURL"
         XMLHTTP.Open "POST", myurl, False
         XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
  
         MsgBox JsonConverter.ConvertToJson(jsonItems, whitespace:=3)
    
         XMLHTTP.Send Body
         MsgBox (XMLHTTP.responseText)
    Next iListRow
End Sub
```

Comment: Please add to your question which `JsonConverter` you are using (there is more than one). Also does the error occur in the line of the message box or anywhere else?

Comment: Have you downloaded an added the JSonConverter at all?

Comment: And if `JsonConverter` is a class object (what it probably is) then you need to declare and initialize it first. In your code it looks like `JsonConverter` is not declared at all and therefore of type `Variant` that's not gonna work. Declare the variable `JsonConverter` as type of your class module first and then initialize a new object using the `Set JsonConverter = New …`  where `…` is replaced by your class name.

Comment: @Peh: As far as I remember, the "classical" VBA JsonConverter  (https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON) declares this automatically.

Comment: @FunThomas Ah well if it's this one, yes it's not a class module (I actually would have had expected one). In this case it should work as the OP did if he installed the `JsonConverter` module.